# DistinctRow returning duplicate rows (MS-Access SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following query with 4 fields. When I run it, there is a lot of duplicate rows. I found many ways to get rid of them, but none of the methods worked. This is the query (with duplicates in the output):

```
SELECT 
R.CODNEG, 
C.FimMês As DATA, 
Format (
         (
         select sum(R2.Rendimento)
         from Rendimentos R2
         where
             R2.CODNEG = R.CODNEG and
             R2.FimMes > dateadd("m", -12, R.FimMes) and
             R2.FimMes <= R.FimMes
         )
          /
         (select sum(C2.VOLTOT) / sum(C2.QUATOT)
         from CotacoesHistoricasNova C2
         where
              C2.CODNEG = C.CODNEG and
              C2.FimMês > dateadd("m", -12, C.FimMês) and
              C2.FimMês <= C.FimMês
         ),
     "Percent") AS DYaa,
Format (
         12*R.Rendimento
         /
         (select sum(C2.VOLTOT) / sum(C2.QUATOT)
         from CotacoesHistoricasNova C2
         where
              C2.CODNEG = C.CODNEG and
              C2.FimMês = C.FimMês
           ),
    "Percent") AS DY12m
FROM 
CotacoesHistoricasNova AS C,
Rendimentos AS R, 
Tickers AS T
WHERE 
     C.CODNEG = T.TickerGde and
     R.CODNEG = T.Ticker and
     C.FimMês = R.FimMes
```

This returns the following output (runs in ~10 sec):
(sample)

```
CODNEG    DATA           DYaa     DY12m
ABCD11    31/jul/2018    5,50%    6,71%
ABCD11    31/jul/2018    5,50%    6,71% <--- duplicate!
...       ...            ...      ...
ABCD11    31/aug/2018    4,41%    7,05%
```

- When I try `DISTINCT`, it runs forever (10 minutes and still
  running...)
- When I try `DISTINCTROW`, it runs in ~10 sec, but the output is the
  same
- When I try `GROUP BY` `R.CODNEG, C.FimMês, DYaa, DY12m`, it returns
  this message:   "Your query does not include the specified expression
  '`Format(12*R.Rendimento/,"Percent")`' as part of an aggregate
  function."

The output is supposed to be like this (no duplicates):
(sample)

```
CODNEG    DATA           DYaa     DY12m
ABCD11    31/jul/2018    5,50%    6,71%
ABCD11    31/aug/2018    4,41%    7,05%
ABCD11    30/sep/2018    3,12%    2,50%
...       ...            ...      ...
XYZW11    31/jan/2018    1,25%    1,64%
XYZW11    28/feb/2018    3,005    2,85%
```

Any ideas why `DISTINCTROW` isn't removing duplicates and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As to why `DISTINCTROW` isn't working in your case, I found a clue in the Microsoft Access help file...

> ...DISTINCTROW is ignored if your query includes only one table, or if
>   you output fields from all tables.

What happens if you create your grouping query as a wrapper to the query you have listed in your post? In other words, save your existing query as a named query in your database, then create a new grouping query and use your first query as the record source. Does that give you better performance than the `DISTINCT` approach?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is creating a resultset where the combination of selected **values** of no two rows are identical, `DISTINCTROW` is creating a resultset where the comination of underlying source **rows** of the selected values of no two rows are identical.